# How to center align the maximum-scale viewport zoom for iphone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, viewport

When I set a maximum scale and when I rotates orientations back and forth, the web page isn't centered on the phone.

So using this code

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0; maximum-scale=2;">
```

How can I mimic the CSS effect of margin: 0 auto;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have a wrapper inside of another wrapper to get this to work. The outside one will have the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
min-width: 320px;
max-width: 480px;
}
```

And the inside one will have the following:

```
#inside-wrapper {
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 460px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can still use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 4):

For people arriving here from Google, you should also look at the following page on Apple[1].

The viewport tag is quite helpful.

[1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html *Using the ViewPort*